# How does non-static method access static members in java?

Tags: java, methods, static, member, non-static

Consider this:

```
class SomeClass
{
   static int a;
   int method()
   {
      int b = a;
      return b;
   }
}
```

How does `a` is being accessed in method? Is it `this.a` or `someClass.a`?

**EDIT:** Sorry if I'm not clear in my question. What I want to know is: *Is there a hidden **this** or **someClass** associated with **a** [in **method**] or is it simply **a** [in **method**] that is accessing the class member?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242649/can-non-static-methods-modify-static-variables

Comment: since its a `static` variable its value is always same, irrespective of how you are trying to access it, you will get same value for `this.a`, `SomeClass.a` or just `a`

Comment: One can consider it a single class member, also accessed as `SomeClass.a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `a`: the same field for *any* instance of the class. You can write `someClass.a` if you need an explicit disambiguation.

Consider carefully *why* you would want a non-static method that returns a static member though: it seems like a code "smell" to me.

Answer (score 1):

I will edit your example in order to make it look a little bit more right:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private static int a = 1;
   public int method()
   {
      int b = a;
      return b;
   }
}
```

`int b = a;` is equal to `int b = SomeClass.a;`

Don't be confused with `this` - it is a reference to an object. Static fields belong to a class, not to an object, so it is incorrect to get `a` with `this.a`

And, as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242649/can-non-static-methods-modify-static-variables):

> Instance methods can access class variables and class methods
>   directly.

Comment: *so it is impossible to get `a` with `this.a`* - Sure?

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside the class you can access it by just calling `a`

From any other class you'll receive this static member by using `someClass.a`

Comment: Or by calling it through an instance, but that is just bad coding.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the static member is public, you can use "SomeClass.a" from any class. For private members, create an accessor method if you really need to access the member and from within the class, just specify it as "a".