# How to use a Get method in java

Tags: java

A ton of questions have been asked on how to create  getter and setter methods in java. But i have yet to see one that actually tells me how to use it.

Say i have `Private int i = 1;` in class A and i want to access it in class B.
I would first create a get method in class A called `getIntI();` which would return the value of i.

Then in class B if i wanted to create an if statement that would need the value of i how would I get int i's value. The following is my try and calling the get method which does not work.

```
if(getIntI == 1)
{System.out.print.ln("int i is one");}
```

It is probably a really stupid question but i cant find an answer for it elsewhere.

Comment: Try with `if(getIntI() == 1)` instead. You need to have parentheses in method calls in Java.

Comment: Your question is not specific to get methods.  Rather your question is how to invoke **any method in java**.  For this example, put parenthesis at the end of the method name, like `getIntI()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In class A:

```
public int getIntI(){
    return i;
}
```

---

*Note:* Now since your variable is single character named (just `I`), getter method is named `getIntI` since the name `getI` makes lesser sense. But generally, getter methods are something like `get+VariableName` and do not involve mentioning type. For example if I had a variable called `int count`, my method would be named `getCount` instead of `getIntCount`. Thats the general convention.

Also, naming variables in single char formats (like `x`, `y` etc) is discouraged because it may create confusion and management difficulty in complex programs. Though in very small programs they are fine.

---

Moving back to topic, if you want to access method `getIntI()` in class B, you will either have to inherit class A or create an object of class A reference to its method.

For class B:

- Creating object

  ```
  A obj = new A();

  if(obj.getIntI() == 1)
      // Do stuff
  ```
- Inheriting class A:

  ```
  public class B extends A{

  ... // Your stuff

      if(getIntI() == 1)
          // Do stuff

  ... // Your stuff
  }
  ```

Of course there are other ways but these are simpler ones.

Comment: why is it sometimes when I use the get method it only works when I use private static int i. when I try to change it so its not static I get a null value when the get method is called.

Comment: Can you show the code where it does that? Also this link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242649/can-non-static-methods-modify-static-variables

Comment: That reflects something wrong with your design; your variables should not be static and the proper fix is something else.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979003/java-using-getter-and-setter-methods-and-returning-0) here is my question regarding my problem. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if `class B extends class A` then do only this changes,

```
if(getIntI() == 1)
```

If above `inheritance was not there` then do this,

```
if(new A().getIntI() == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to create a object derived from class A before you can access its variables/methods using

```
A a = new A();
```

where "a" is the name of the object. Then you can access the getter method by calling `a.getIntI`. 
You can also declare the int variable as static so that you wouldn't have to instantiate any objects. An example of class A with the static variable and getter method would be:

```
public class A {

    private static int i = 1;

    public static int getIntI() {   
        return i;
    }

}
```

With this, you can call the getter method with `A.getIntI()`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to access one of `A`'s non-static methods (in this case, `getIntI`), you need an instance of `A`, or you can just declare it static.

Secondly, A method call needs a *parameter list*, even an empty one is needed. `getIntI` does not need any parameters, so you should add `()` at the end.

Now, you can get an instance of `A` somewhere and call it `aObj`. Andd then you can use it in the if statement:

```
if (aObj.getIntI == 1)
```

And remember to add `()`!

```
if (aObj.getIntI() == 1)
```

Alternatively, you can declare `i` in `A` as *static*. There are two main differences between a static and a non-static variable.

- You don't need an instance of the declaring class to access the static variable.
- Unlike non-static variables, there is only one static variable. If you have a non-static variable `i`, you can create lots of instances of `A` and each instance will have its own `i`

Now let's see this in action, declare `i` as static:

```
public class A {
    private static int i = 1;
    public static int getIntI () { return i; }
}
```

Note how both `i` and `getIntI` are declared static.

Then you can use in a if statement like this:

```
if (A.getIntI() == 1)
```

Note how I use the class name `A` to access the method, not an instance of `A`.