# Can I use non static variable in static method in java?

Tags: java

> "write a program in java that declare a class with one integer data member and two member functions in() and out() to input and output data in data member."

My current code is as follows.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Operator 
{ 
    static int a;
    public static void input() { 
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter the number:"); 
        a=in.Nextint(); //Here is problem 
    }

    public static void output() { 
        System.out.println("Number is:" + a); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        input();
        output();
    } 
}
```

Comment: nope. Make an instance or make it static.

Comment: The body of your "question" is unrelated to the title. What are you asking?

Comment: plz just write the code of above statement I'll be thankfull

Comment: @RanaHamzaKhursheed we are not here to do your homework. Show us what you did, and we might help you!

Comment: No. What have you done? What are you stuck on? We're not here to do your assignments.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operator {
    static int a;
    
    public static void input()
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter the number:");
        a=in.Nextint(); //Here is problem 
    }
    public static void output()
    {
        System.out.println("Number is:" + a);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        input();
        output();
        
    }
    
}

Comment: I have declared a static variable and want to input value in that in a member function using Scanner but ...

Comment: @RanaHamzaKhursheed Please modify your question: add what is the problem with your current code (what doesn't work as expected).

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to be confused w.r.t instance variables and local variables.

You can always declare a "local variable" inside a static method.
main() for example is a static function and we always declare variables inside it.

So your creation of a variable "in" of type Scanner inside input() function is perfectly fine.

However, you "cannot" access instance variables and instance methods from static methods.

This post on stack overflow gives a full and complete answer: [Can non-static methods modify static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242649/can-non-static-methods-modify-static-variables)

As far as your code is concerned, there's a minor error in the code.
The function call to read an integer is "nextInt" and not "Nextint". Java generally uses camel-case to define all its methods. So be careful with the method usage.

The modified code should be this:

```
class Operator
{
    static int a;
    public static void input() { 
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter the number:"); 
        a=in.nextInt(); //this is nextInt and NOT Nextint
    }

    public static void output() { 
        System.out.println("Number is:" + a); 
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        input();
        output();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer - NO
reason is simple too, that is - it will violates the definition of static i.e. accessible in other class without creating a object(also called instance) of the class.

[image]

**But, what if we try to do static variable in a non-static method ?**
In that case, YES we can do that. Because we have to create a instance (object) of the class to use that method. So, that doesn't violates the definition.

[image]