# Static Variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, static

I know that static variables are part of class and not part of the Object . How can the following lines of code work without any problem

```
class M
{
  static int i=0;
  void Inc()
  {
    System.out.println("Global "+M.i);
    System.out.println("Local "+this.i);
  }
}    

public class StaticTest
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    M m1=new M();
    m1.i=99;       //How can the m1 object access i variable of the class
    m1.Inc();
   }  
}
```

The output i get is

```
Global 99
Local 99
```

How can the m1 object access i variable of the class?

Comment: All instance variable share that static variable. You've referenced it incorrectly, but it stills runs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242649/can-non-static-methods-modify-static-variables

Answer (score 1):

It is the very same *i* variable in both cases.

*unfortunately*, java allows you to access static fields using `non-static` syntax.

That is all there is to this, nothing else behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is allowed for non-static members to access and update static members.

See this for more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242649/can-non-static-methods-modify-static-variables)