# Can a static variable be access by nonstatic functions?

Tags: c++, function, static, non-static

My questions is: if a static variable (access level: private) is defined in a class and we want to access it by non static function of that class. .  is it possible in c++?

Comment: Have you tried to do this? It would take less effort than this post. live link: https://godbolt.org/g/U4291s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.

This question was already somewhat asked here: [Can non-static methods modify static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242649/can-non-static-methods-modify-static-variables)

You are just asking if it can access it though - I am fairly certain if you can modify something, that means you can also access it.